# 'NoneType' 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, metatrader5

I am trying to loop through a list of symbols to get rates for various currencies via the mt5. I use the code below but i get TypeError

```
     d[i] = [y.close for y in rates1]
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I can't see where im going wrong i would like to use this structure to loop through create multiple dataframe and then make a big multiindex of all pairs and time using same kind of loop. I've not been coding long.

```
sym = ['GBPUSD','USDJPY','USDCHF','AUDUSD','GBPJPY']

# Copying data to dataframe
d = pd.DataFrame()
for i in sym:
     rates1 = mt5.copy_rates_from(i, mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 5)
     d[i] = [y.close for y in rates1]
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun 29 18:38:11 2020

@author: DanPc
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

"""

import pytz
import pandas as pd
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
import talib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys


server_name = "" ENTER DETAILS HERE
server_num = 
password = ""



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def actualtime():
    # datetime object containing current date and time
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    #print("date and time =", dt_string)
    return str(dt_string)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def sync_60sec(op):

    info_time_new = datetime.strptime(str(actualtime()), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    waiting_time = 60 - info_time_new.second

    t = Timer(waiting_time, op)
    t.start()

    print(actualtime)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def program(symbol):
    if not mt5.initialize(login=server_num, server=server_name, password=password):
        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
        quit()

    timezone = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")
    utc_from = datetime.now()

    ######### Change here the timeframe 525600
  
    
   # Create currency watchlist for which correlation matrix is to be plotted
sym = ['GBPUSD','USDJPY','USDCHF','AUDUSD','GBPJPY']

# Copying data to dataframe
d = pd.DataFrame()
for i in sym:
     rates1 = mt5.copy_rates_from(i, mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 5)
     d[i] = [y.close for y in rates1]
    
    
print(rates1)
    
mt5.shutdown()

  
if not mt5.initialize():
        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
        quit()

         
# starting mt5
if not mt5.initialize(login=server_num, server=server_name, password=password):
    print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
    quit()          
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                   S T A R T I N G   M T 5 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
authorized=mt5.login(server_num, password=password)
if authorized:
    account_info=mt5.account_info()
    if account_info!=None:       
        account_info_dict = mt5.account_info()._asdict()
        df=pd.DataFrame(list(account_info_dict.items()),columns=['property','value'])
        print("account_info() as dataframe:")
        print(df)
else:
    print(mt5.last_error)

mt5.shutdown()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def trading_bot():
    symbol_1 = 'EURUSD'
    symbol_2 = 'EURCAD'
    while True:
        program(symbol_1)
        program(symbol_2)
        time.sleep(59.8) # it depends on your computer and ping

sync_60sec(trading_bot)
```

Comment: Well, `rates1` is simply `None`.

Comment: Thanks i was missing utc_from . rates1 = mt5.copy_rates_from(i, mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, utc_from ,  60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy_rates_from` returns `None` if there is an error. The documentation suggests calling [`last_error()`](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5lasterror_py) to find out what that error is.

(And no, I don't know why `copy_rates_from` doesn't just raise an exception to indicate the error. Apparently, the module is a thin wrapper around a C library.)

Comment: Thanks. I didnt specify time as UTC.  (utc_from ,)

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution that creates a dictionary of dataframes.

```
sym = ["GBPUSD","USDJPY","USDCHF","AUDUSD","GBPJPY"]


# Copying data to dataframe

utc_from = datetime.now()
for i in sym:
  rates = {i:pd.DataFrame(mt5.copy_rates_from(i, mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, utc_from , 60), 
                 columns=['time', 'open', 'low', 'high', 'close', 'tick_volume', 'spread', 'real_volume']) for i in sym}
```